# Expressjs JSON object and Array change form over POST request

Tags: node.js, express

I'm writing a web application with `Express.js`. When sending data in request body, any Array or Object with number key automatically parse as below:

```
{object1: {23: "abc", 45: "def"}, array1: ["a", "b"]}
```

get parsed into:

```
{"object1[23]": "abc", "object1[45]": "def", "array1[0]": "a", "array1[1]": "b"}
```

This is really annoying because when I try to retrieve key `object1` or `array1`, I got error key does not exists and I have to do `object1[23]` instead.

Comment: This is entirely dependent upon what middleware you're using to parse the request. Express does not parse request data itself.

Comment: I use the middleware provided by `express-generator`. I think it's called `body parser`. Do you have any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 things which could lead to this issue -

1. the array size is larger that 20 (express default limit is 20)
2. the array is at some deeper level in the object (express default limit is 5)

to solve any of these issue 
first require 'qs' in your app.js (file where app is iniatlized)

```
const qs = require('qs');
```

then before making the use calls (app.use(  ))
set the limits (it ll not work if written after use calls)

```
app.set('query parser', function (str) {
    //to allow to receive objects with depths upto 10
    return qs.parse(str, { depth: 10 });
    // return qs.parse(str, {arrayLimit:1000}); to allow arrays of size 1000
});
```